# Adjust UIView position for iPhoneX / iPad / iPhone6 within a statement

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Updating some old code and have fixed everything aside from one pesky button inside a `UIView` that does not show in the correct place only on certain devices.

It works and positions perfectly for all iPad devices, and works for iPhoneX / XS & XR

However for iPhone 5,5s,6,6s,7,8 the button is not showing in correct place.

I understand this is a 'dirty' fix however it is literally this one button causing the issues, the rest of the code itself works perfectly, so I didn't want to reinvent the wheel as such.

This image position itself is set like this;

```
 #define IDIOM    UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()
#define IPAD     UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad

if ( IDIOM == IPAD ) {
     [nail5View setFrame:CGRectMake(638, 682, nail5View.frame.size.width, nail5View.frame.size.height)]; // was 358,582
} else {
[nail5View setFrame:CGRectMake(358, 582, nail5View.frame.size.width, nail5View.frame.size.height)];
}

nail5View.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(+0.9);
nail5View.transform = transform;
```

Is there a way I can specifically target the iPhones lower than X to add an extra position just for those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check the device is iphone 8plus or lesser model like thise

```
#define iPhone8AndLesser ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height <= 736)
```

if you want iphone 8 and lesse use 667 insted of 736
and you can check it by using

```
if ( IDIOM == IPAD ) {
     [nail5View setFrame:CGRectMake(638, 682, nail5View.frame.size.width, nail5View.frame.size.height)]; // was 358,582
} else {
if iPhone8AndLesser{
    //Your conditions here;
}else{
  [nail5View setFrame:CGRectMake(358, 582, nail5View.frame.size.width, nail5View.frame.size.height)];
}
}
```